# Can you add a function to your iphone messages app?

Tags: iphone, message

Ok so I am curious if you can add a function to you iphones messages app?  If you open the messages app in the top right corner you can hit edit, which then allows you to delete and forward the selected messages.  Is there a way to add another function to that?  Or even a way  you can access these messages through another app (like a program that then has messages running through it).

I am basically trying to have an app where a user can sent someone else messages by selecting which ones they want the other user to see.  It would basically be like taking a screen shot of the phone but taking a screen shot then sending it is too complicated and can include a message you don't want the other user to see.

Answer (score 1):

I am 100% sure there is no way to change the behavior of the built-in Messages app on an iOS devices without jailbreaking.

I am 99% sure that Apple does not provide any hooks for getting information from a users Messages app.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to do on android?

Comment: @Chris I don't do Android development, sorry.

Comment: Alright well thanks.  I figured that would be the case